# After connection of mysql with node js global variable value showing undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js

After connection of mysql from node js global variable value showing undefined inside connection.What should we do so that it give the correct value?

```
var a = "100000";
var con = mysql.createConnection({
                    host: "xyz.com",
                    user: "db",
                    password: "db",
                    database: "truck"
         });
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
    var p = a.substring(0,1);//p is 1 now
    con.connect(function(err) {                                
    con.query("SELECT * FROM at_device_fault", function (err, result, fields) {
              console.log(p);//here p is undefined here what should do for correct value(1)?
         });
    });
}
```

Comment: Is that the _actual_ code that you're using?

Comment: No, this is not my actual code

Comment: Ultimately, I think it's related to your use of `var`. You should read up on how `var` variables are scoped and how that may interfere with asynchronous code. If you'd use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) instead of `var` it will probably be solved.

Comment: thank you very much@robertklep....finally solved using let

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this problem using let

```
var a = "100000";
var con = mysql.createConnection({
                host: "xyz.com",
                user: "db",
                password: "db",
                database: "truck"
     });
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
let p = a.substring(0,1);//p is 1 now
con.connect(function(err) {                                
con.query("SELECT * FROM at_device_fault", function (err, result, fields) {

          console.log(p);//here p is 1 now
     });
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not asking "Why". The function, inside which p is undefined, is a "callback" which will executed after the asynchronous query finally completes. The execution will not wait for it to complete, it will rather give it to event loop and will jump to the next iteration immeriately. One can't say for sure what will be the value of p when the callback will be finally executed after the completion of the query. For this reason only const variables can be used inside callbacks because they donot change their value.